# Connect to SuperWebSocket Server through JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, websocket

I've created a Sample Application based on [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) (running v0.3). I manage to get connect to the WebSocket Server through Telnet, but for some reason I'm having trouble doing it through JavaScript (running Chrome 17.0.963.46 m).

Through Telnet I can connect through either localhost:911 or 192.168.1.147:911.

My Application is running on http://localhost/Raphael-Test/, and I've tried running through both localhost and the local networks IP, both gets stuck at "Connecting" ie. status 0.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing, any configuration that should be done in the Web Application itself? I should add that I've successfully tried out the LiveChat demo, got it working through JavaScript.

This is my current Client Implementation running when the Page has been fully loaded:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.147:911");
ws.onopen = function () {
    alert("connected");
};
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var msg = evt.data;
    alert(msg);
};
```

Handshake (with NO response):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 192.168.1.147:911
Origin: http://192.168.1.147
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 8bl46pmPrixTYRJ/5i9Sug==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

Comment: It's probably a dumb question, but have you verified that SuperWebSocket` is *actually* listening on port 991 (through `netstat`)?

Comment: Yes, and as I said I can connect to it through Telnet. So the server should be fine :)

Comment: @Herber I am dying for the past 10 days to create a websocketserver using SuperWebSocket. If you post your code in this page, I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I used the SuperSocket Server base classes instead of SuperWebSocket on the server side. This made the TCP connection itself work as expected, but did of course not handle the WebSocket Handshake and therefore the connection failed.

Comment: I am dying for the past 10 days to create a websocketserver using SuperWebSocket. If you post your code in this page, I will be very thankful to you.